# How's the support for multiple monitors in ubuntu, using a graphic card from AMD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

How is the support for multiple monitors in ubuntu (10.04) when using a graphic cards from AMD(/ATI), for example the HD 5770.

I know that DP is required to use three monitors on a regular card. But other than that, will it work? Am I to expect a lot of work to be able to get it working? Or will it simply be impossible? (And yes, I know that AMDs(/ATI) drivers aren't always the best. Although changing to a card from Nvidia at this moment isn't possible)

The background to my question is that I'm thinking about buying another monitor, same model as the current one I'm using, and later on perhaps expand to buy another one.

Tried to search for it but wasn't able to find how the support would be in linux, and ubuntu in particular, since most I found is about the windows support, which should work quite easy and therefore isn't relevant.

Comment: Bought a new monitor, and so far there isn't any problems at all with the two together . Looks like amds drivers is working as they're supposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data point: I currently have a dual-monitor Linux machine with an older (1xxx series) ATI card using the `radeon` driver. In my limited experience (but not limited to one machine), if you can get ATI drivers to work at all, a second monitor is not a problem (unlike nvidia where you need the closed-source driver to use more than one monitor, unless this has changed recently).

Comment: If that's correct then I probably should be able to get it working without that much difficulty...

Answer (score 1):

Currently using an HD 3400 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and it works perfectly with dual monitors. Got one on HDMI and one on normal VGA.